# Changing Account password using rules

Tags: 7, rules

I'm using rules module in my site (drupal 7), i want to create a small form to the user to change his password without going to (account editing page).

This form contain 3 textbox (old passowrd, new password, confirm new password).

Can i make this form using rules?
or is there another module can help me with that?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You cannot create forms using Rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32722/how-can-i-display-a-change-password-form-on-its-own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to make a custom page using hook_menu(), and have a submit function on that page that would check the user's authentication, and if it was correct, change the current password.

If you need a bit more information on that, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Rules won't help you build a user interface, however the [password_policy](http://drupal.org/project/password_policy) module provides a dedicated user profile tab for changing password and may be of interest.

> ...a password tab available to users instead of the usual user/#/edit
>   screen for password changes.