# How can I display a reset password form on its own?

Tags: users

Thanks a lot for your posting about building a form on its own to change user password.
I used your suggested approach and I coud implement easily many isolated forms to let people change password, avatar, and so on.

What I cannot solve is how to use the same logic to reset forgotten password on a form on its own called from the one-time login link.

I tried this:
- I installed module Login Destinations and added the following destination rule triggered on one-time login link:

```
    global $user; 
    // Let the user's password be changed without the current password check.
    $token = drupal_hash_base64(drupal_random_bytes(55));
    $_SESSION['pass_reset_' . $user->uid] = $token;
    return array('change-password', array('query' => array('pass-reset-token' => $token)));
```

It is triggered from user/reset/*.

- change-password is my custom form implemented like this.

  ```
  function _tb_user_render_user_pass_set_new_form() {
    global $user;
    if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
      drupal_access_denied();
    }

    module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
    $form = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user);
    $children = element_children($form);

    foreach ($children as $child) {
      if (!($child == 'account' || $child == 'actions' || $child == 'form_build_id' || $child == 'form_token' || $child == 'form_id' || $child == 'current_id' || $child == 'revision_id' || $child == 'current_date')) {
        unset($form[$child]);
      }
    }

    $children = element_children($form['account']);
    foreach ($children as $child) {
      if (!($child == 'current_pass_required_values' || $child == 'pass')) {
        unset($form['account'][$child]);
      }
    }

    return $form;
  }
  ```

It does't work since it still requires current password.

Do you have any idea on how to do that properly?

Comment: [This might help](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32722/how-can-i-display-a-change-password-form-on-its-own/32725#32725). If you just remove the validation handler and current password field it should do what you want