# Separating user edit form into small descent form

Tags: 7, forms, users

I am developing a Community website in Drupal 7,where users got profiles with many fields, but these fields are grouped for Example: Basic informations,Hobbies, Education,Experience and So on..
In normal drupal, when user wants to edit his profile, he/she will be present with a huge form with lots of fields.
What i need is to separate these categories in different small forms, if possible using a custom module so the forms can be called like 
   drupal_get_form('basic_informations');
   drupal_get_form('Hobbies');
If This will be possible then i will be able to opens this small forms in modal dialogs(ctools).

Any suggestion will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No need for custom forms!

[Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) will do all of the items you require! Here is [the handbook](http://drupal.org/node/1074296) to get you started.

This will let you have different forms (tabs) on the /user page and you can also choose which of those "subforms" you want on the user registration.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the Profile2 module. After a search i found this thread, they solved the issue programmatically something which i was looking        http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32722/how-can-i-display-a-change-password-form-on-its-own