# How to add field update your password in drupal webform?

Tags: hooks, webforms

I want to add **three fields** in webform:

1. Current password
2. New password
3. New Password Again

Current password should be existing password and  last two fields(New password ,New Password Again)should update only if  current password is correct(validated). In short I only wants to add "update your password functionality" in my website using webform .

Any Idea how to do this ?

Comment: Any reason you want to use webform for this? To what I understand, webform is used when we need to store and analyse the submisssions or have access restrictions for the forms.

Comment: @webrole!!!My client needs this functionality it is just project requirement

Comment: I feel, Drupal webform is suggested when requirement is to store and analyse submissions. I am not sure why webform module is needed in this case. However, I am sharing a link to the alternative solution for this, instead of using drupal webform. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/32724

Answer (score 0):

[Webform Password Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_password_field)

> This module allows you to add a password component to a webform. It
>   doesn't validate the password in any way.

Comment: i already Have this module dear i just want to know how to perform above action how to update your password